# ax.fill() in matplotlib filling wrong area

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a Lorenz Curve using matplotlib and I wanted to fill the area below the Lorenz Curve, here's how I wrote the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
# I used seaborn for different styles.

x = [0, 0.10304926499801351, 0.20455899880810488, 0.30986789829161698,
0.41132796980532377, 0.51018077075883983, 0.61201330949543098,
0.71223182359952319, 0.81185439014700034, 0.91063269765593957,
1.0]

y = [0, 0.016037735849056604, 0.033018867924528301, 0.063207547169811321,
0.087735849056603782, 0.13962264150943399, 0.20000000000000001,
0.27547169811320754, 0.37264150943396224, 0.53018867924528301,
1.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill(x, y, 'b', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

It ends up something like this:

[image]

Clearly it is not working as expected since I'd like to fill the area BELOW the curve.

I tried with some other examples like this one:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 500)
y1 = np.sin(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill(x, y1, 'b', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

and they all worked fine. I must have missed something in my own plot but can't figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: The reason `ax.fill` is working for the sin curve is that `sin(0)==sin(2*pi)==0`. You may try to let x run up to `np.pi/2.` and you will get a very different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `fill_between` instead of `fill`. 
`fill` fills the area between the points of the curve. The result you get is therefore expected. 
[`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) fills the area between the curce and some other curve or constant `y` value.

Using

```
ax.fill_between(x, y, y2=0, color='b', alpha=0.3)
```

you get the area between the y=0 zero line and your curve filled:

[image]